# Is this a right way to update a global golang map with concurrent read?

Tags: go

this is a fatal error: concurrent map read and map write demo code:

```
package main

var Map = make(map[int]int)

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        go updateMap()
        go readMap(i)
    }

}

func readMap(key int) int {
    return Map[key]
}

func updateMap() {
    for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
        Map[j] = j
    }
}
```

I don't use the lock or sync.Map, just use tmp var to replace global map, it will not panic, codes like this:

```
package main

var Map = make(map[int]int)

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        go updateMap()
        go readMap(i)
    }

}

func readMap(key int) int {
    return Map[key]
}

func updateMap() {
    tmp := map[int]int{}
    for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
        tmp[j] = j
    }
    Map = tmp
}
```

Is there any problem with this way to update the global map?

Comment: Depends on what you want. The second code won't panic but you don't have any guarantees with the value you will read either. Highly recommend `go run -race` if eliminating race conditions is a concern.

Comment: To be sure you should use a waitgroup and wait for all goroutines to end properly before finish your program.

Answer (score 1):

The second way of updating the map will not panic, because the map being updated is a temporary map, but there is still a race condition. After the `updateMap` function, there is no guarantee when the other goroutine will see the effects of `updateMap`, if ever.

The correct way is to use a `RWMutex` for both cases. The `readMap` should use `RLock/RUnlock`, and `updateMap` should use `Lock/Unlock`. For the second case, if the `updateMap` the only goroutine that ever updates the map, you can use `Rlock/RUnlock` during the copy phase, and `Lock/Unlock` when you assign the map.